# Youtube api v3 sample for uploading videos under .net

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

As the youtube api v3 sample for uploading videos under c# .net does not compile in visual studio 2010, please upload a working solution zip file containing all necessary dependencies for those having the same problem.

A zip file containing sln, csproj etc. of a working(!) project uploading video files to youtube using the v3 of the api(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: It's the profile of visual studio. Select your project in the solution manager and press Alt+Enter. Choose Target framework: ".net Framework 4" instead of ".net Framework 4 Client Profile".